# What is the official logo of the BIPM?

Tags: measurement

The logo on the [BIPM's (International Bureau of Weights and Measures) site](https://www.bipm.org/en/about-us/) is this:

[image]

However, when I visit the English (and, most importantly, French) Wikipedia articles on BIPM, and also when I google "BIPM logo", I mostly get the following image:
[image]

**So, which one is the current BIPM's logo?**

I suspect that the second image is BIPM's first logo, and the modern logo is now on their official site, though I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The Greek means "Through measure, I furnish", a maxim of  Pittacus of Mytilene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BIPM website contains copies of several memoranda of understanding between BIPM and other organisations, which indicate that there are *two* distinct pictorial symbols that represent BIPM: one called the "emblem" and one called the "seal".

The first of the two images presented by OP (the one with the three vertical lines and the sans serif text) has been registered as a trade mark in the US, Singapore, and Canada.  The Singaporean registration record describes it as the "emblem".  Hence, I deduce that the second image presented by OP (the circular one with the three classical humanoid figures) is the "seal".

The lexico.com thesaurus lists both "emblem" and "seal" as synonyms of "logo", so as far as the original question goes, take your pick.